# HERE-Routing API - "These credentials do not authorize access"

Tags: here-api, here-routing

I have signed up to the free HERE account, with billing information.

The search function works fine, and returns expected results, however the calculateroute function throws up "These credentials do not authorize access" as 403.

I have registered a new map, and added to a project linked to the Route API, however I still cannot get it to work.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

It seems V7 is oboslete. Using v8 has solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

What is the HTTP Status Codes returned ?

- 401
- 403

If 403 response, maybe **calculateroute function** is not available for free accounts ? (Your message "These credentials do not authorize access" may means that...)

You will find here list of status codes form here api: [Routing API HTTP status code](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/http-status-codes.html)

Comment: It is indeed a 403 response. I was under the impression from the docs that this was included as part of the free account. I shall look into alternatives.